# How to Admin setTemplate?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, magento-community, adminform

I've found this question and in the answer someone says to set the template as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035891/create-a-form-in-magento-admin-panel/16841794#16841794.

Where can I put my fileName.phtml ?

Really need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all adminhtml templates live in app/design/adminhtml/{package}/{theme}/template.